# Android-studio 3.0-beta6 aapt failed in libc++.so

Tags: linux, aapt, libc++, android-studio-3.0, android-gradle-3.0

I'm starting to get aapt error in `mergeDebugResources` task after updating to Android-Studio beta-6 and gradle to 3.0.0-beta6:

```
:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
> /tmp/aapt2_2254604547909969947/libc++.so: /tmp/aapt2_2254604547909969947/libc++.so: failed to map segment from shared object
```

file info:

```
file /tmp/aapt2_2254604547909969947/libc++.so
/tmp/aapt2_2254604547909969947/libc++.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped, with debug_info
```

OS: `Linux 4.8.17-r2`

What went wrong and how to hix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I got this error `failed to map segment from shared object` because of `noexec` flag in my `/tmp` dir:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,noatime,size=2G,nodev,mode=1777,noexec,nosuid
```

So I've had to remove this flag and remount partition.